# Create a user via the Azure API management Rest service

Tags: c#, api, rest, azure

I'm new to Azure API management Rest Service. I created a new API Management, with a `sharedaccesstoken`.

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", sharedAccessSignature);
    request.Content = new StringContent("{\"accountEnabled\": true,\"creationType\": \"LocalAccount\",\"displayName\": \"Alex Wu\",\"passwordProfile\": {\"password\": \"Test1234\",\"forceChangePasswordNextLogin\": false},\"signInNames\": [{\"type\": \"userName\",\"value\": \"AlexW\"},{\"type\": \"emailAddress\",\"value\": \"AlexW@example.com\"}]}");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

When i execute the code above i get a error:

```
{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Date: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 19:38:15 GMT  Content-Length: 73  Allow: GET  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}}
```

Can someone help me moving forward so I will be able to create new users via the REST service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read up on the API Reference specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/createorupdate.

For starters, you should use HttpMethod.Put instead of Post. The request path should be base url + /users/{unique uid}. Also, from what I can tell, the attributes you are trying to pass are not available for this transaction.

If it's something else you're actually trying to accomplish then creating an Azure API Management User Entity, please advice and I'll try to guide you further.

Comment: The URL to create a user through the API Management REST Services has changed:


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/createorupdate

Answer (score 0):

Your answer helped me indeed. Below the implementation which made me accomplish my task.

```
  string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/users/{1}?api-version={2}", baseUrl, userGuid, apiVersion);
            string responseBody = null;
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                { 
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, requestUrl);
                        request.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedAccessSignature", sharedAccessSignature);
                        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"firstName\": \"MyFirstName\",\"lastName\": \"MyLastName\",\"email\": \"example@mail\",\"password\": \"Password;\",\"state\": \"active\"}", Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`enter code here`
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
            }
```